# Yii error Cannot read property 'submitForm' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, yii

i am new in Yii, when i click my submit button am getting an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'submitForm' of undefined"
here is my code

view page

```
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm(); ?>

        <div class="search">
            <div class="form-group">
            <?php echo CHtml::textField('search','',
                        array('placeholder'=>'Search Your products')); ?>
                <!--<input type="text" placeholder="Search Your products"/>-->
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <?php 
                $options = array();
                    foreach ($model as $user) :
                        $options[] = $user[0];

                    endforeach;

                echo CHtml::dropDownList('mySelect', '12', $options);


            ?>
                <!--<select>
                    <option>Option One</option>
                    <option>Option Two</option>
                    <option>Option Three</option>
                    <option>Option Four</option>
                    <option>Option Five</option>
                </select>-->
            </div>

             <div class="form-group_new">
             <?php 
                echo CHtml::button('SEARCH YOUR PRODUCT', array('submit'=>array('Product/index'),'class'=>'search-bttn','placeholder'=>'Search')); 

             ?>
                <!--<input type="submit" placeholder="Search" value="SEARCH YOUR PRODUCT" class="search-bttn"/>-->
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

when i run this nothing happens except showing error.Can anyone help me with this??? Waiting for a response..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

forgive the English , you need to add the jquery Yii
jquery.yii.js

Comment: Thanks for your reply